# Will low grades on my transcript ruin my chances of getting into an MBA program, even if I retake classes for course forgiveness?

Tags: masters, undergraduate, gpa

I'm sure this question has been asked frequently. However, I'm an undergrad, currently finished my sophomore first semester. I have gotten Ds (twice currently, not in the same semesters) on my transcripts due to mental health issues and having not withdrawn before the drop deadline. However, I have retaken the first D and plan to retake the other as well under course forgiveness. They won't be factored in my GPA but they will show up on my transcript. I just wanted to know how bad grades on transcript would affect my chances when will applying to MBA programs?

Answer (score 2):

You will have the opportunity to discuss your transcript in your Personal Statement when you apply. You may choose to discuss it or not, you may have a better story you may want to talk in lieu of it later in your life, i.e a project you worked on, an internship, etc.